# Forward external call to localhost

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, port-forwarding, localhost

I have an emulator software, which can communicate via telnet protocol and simulate an optical measurement unit.
I can connect to the emulator if I use localhost (127.0.0.1) and 4550 port.

I have to reach it from an other PC so I would like to set a forwarding rule on my PC if it is possible. Unfortunately I did not find any options for it.

Other PC (192.168.2.112) ---Telnet---> PC (192.168.2.200:4550) ---forward--->localhost (127.0.0.1:4550)

Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What OS? Internal or external network?

Comment: Windows 10 and internal network.